# Broadcasting a video from a UDP stream with Amazon Chime

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp, aws-chime-sdk

I have an UDP stream of a video rtp h264. I would like to broadcast the video in real time.
I would like to use AWS Chime SDK in order to acheive this.

I am currencly able to forward the UDP video to an OBS Virtual Camera using ffmpeg and then using the virtual camera as source in a Chime sdk meeting. But I am confident that this is not the best approach.

Is there a way to connect the udp rtp h264 video stream to aws chime sdk without using a virtual camera?

Ideally feasable in Javascript. But can use c++ instead if the c++ version of aws chime sdk
offers more functionalities than the JS version.
I have scouted the aws documentation unsucessfully.